# How to create an NxM matrix with each column value in range(x,y)?

Tags: python, numpy

Problem: 
I want to create a 5 dimensional numpy matrix, each column's value restricted to a range. I can't find any solution online for this problem.

I'm trying to generate a list of rules in the form

```
Rule: (wordIndex, row, col, dh, dv)
```

with each column having values in range ( (0-7), (0,11), (0,11), (-1,1), (-1,1) ). I want to generate all possible combinations.

I could easily make the matrix using five loops, one inside another

```
m, n = 12, 12
rules =[]
for wordIndex in range(0, 15):
    for row in range(0,m):
        for col in range(0,n):
            for dh in range(-1,2):
                for dv in range(-1,2):
                    rules.append([wordIndex, row, col, dh, dv])
```

But this approach takes an exponentially large time to do this and I wonder if there's a better, vectorized approach to solve this problem using numpy.

I've tried the following but none seem to work:

```
rules = np.mgrid[words[0]:words[-1], 0:11, 0:11, -1:1, -1:1]
rules = np.rollaxis(words,0,4)
rules = rules.reshape((len(words)*11*11*3*3, 5))
```

Another approach that fails:

```
values = list(itertools.product(len(wordsGiven()), range(11), range(11), range(-1,1), range(-1,1)))
```

I also tried np.arange() but can't seem to figure out how to use if for a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be a better way for it. But just in case if you cannot find it, here is a hacky array based way for it:

```
shape = (8-0, 12-0, 12-0, 2-(-1), 2-(-1))
a = np.zeros(shape)
#create array of indices
a = np.argwhere(a==0).reshape(*shape, len(shape))
#correct the ranges that does not start from 0, here 4th and 5th elements (dh and dv) reduced by -1 (starting range). 
#You can adjust this for any other ranges and elements easily.
a[:,:,:,:,:,3:5] -= 1
```

First few elements of a:

```
[[[[[[ 0  0  0 -1 -1]
     [ 0  0  0 -1  0]
     [ 0  0  0 -1  1]]

    [[ 0  0  0  0 -1]
     [ 0  0  0  0  0]
     [ 0  0  0  0  1]]

    [[ 0  0  0  1 -1]
     [ 0  0  0  1  0]
     [ 0  0  0  1  1]]]


   [[[ 0  0  1 -1 -1]
     [ 0  0  1 -1  0]
     [ 0  0  1 -1  1]]

    [[ 0  0  1  0 -1]
     [ 0  0  1  0  0]
     [ 0  0  1  0  1]]

    [[ 0  0  1  1 -1]
     [ 0  0  1  1  0]
     [ 0  0  1  1  1]]]


   [[[ 0  0  2 -1 -1]
     [ 0  0  2 -1  0]
     [ 0  0  2 -1  1]]

    [[ 0  0  2  0 -1]
     [ 0  0  2  0  0]
     [ 0  0  2  0  1]]

    [[ 0  0  2  1 -1]
     [ 0  0  2  1  0]
     [ 0  0  2  1  1]]]


   ...
```